# Allow user to select between 1 minute and 1 year, best ux

Tags: usability

For one of my inputs I want the user to be able to select a duration, which can be between 1 minute and 1 year

If they're working in the minute area it should be easy to select 1 vs 10 minutes. Easy to chose 1hr vs 4 hours. Easy to chose 1 day vs 2 days, etc...

I was thinking to use a horizontal slider but can't figure how to make it work across all these time frames.

The best I could come up with is 4 horizontal sliders, and let the user drag them to form the duration they want

minutes 1-60, hours 1-24, days 1-6, weeks 1-52

This isn't a super duper frequent site activity but this does seem cumbersome

Any other ways I might organize the user select to allow a user to chose anything time duration between a minute and a year?

Comment: May the user choose mixed parameters: 3 h 16 min?

Comment: What about a number input and a dropdown (minutes, hours, days, weeks)? This way users could also specify 3h 16 min as 196 min.

Comment: Is this a case where the user will want something really specific, or would they appreciate the system making suggestions? Example: "Remind me in 1 hour / 1 day / 1 month / 1 year."

Comment: @Izquierdo ah good idea, yes they would find it helpful to select 1 min / 1 hour / 1 day / 1 week, and scroll from there

Comment: Adding to some other unanswered questions from the comments here: Can users select combinations of weeks, days, hours, and minutes (2 weeks AND 6 days AND 14 hours) or are they just working with more rounded numbers on one single scale (3 weeks OR 21 days OR 494 hours, etc)?

Comment: @RouxMartin users should be able to select an arbitrary date between 1 minute and 1 year ... so while they should be able to select 529 hours, it would make more sense to most people to select 3 weeks 1 day and 1 hour. It doesn't have to be optimized to select exactly that amount though, as in that case the user would probably be content to select approx 3 weeks and a day

Comment: One more question: What's keeping you from just using labelled text inputs that only validate for numeric values? something like: Weeks:[2]  Days:[6]  Hours[14]  Minutes:[0] is there some other need that you're meeting by having something more complex?

Answer (score 1):

One example that I found to be quite easy for the user to visually see the different time frames:
[image]
https://123timer.com/

You can add another column for Month, Year etc...

Another option is to have a drop down for each time period:
[image]
https://dollyclock.com/timer-online

Comment: The second example is a winner, possibly with the label on top of the dropdown. 
It shows the users what each timeframe is, and it has a default value already (00). In addition to that, it has high affordability by also showing the dropdown arrow to clearly mark interactive elements.